# Simple OLS with two samples

Tags: least-squares, unbiased-estimator

I want to obtain an unbiased estimator for $b_1$ in a simple regression like that: $Y_i = B_0 + B_1X_i + u_i$ when I have two samples, always same size for Y and X, but once the sample size is l and once the sample size is m. The respective sample means $\bar{Y_l},\bar{X_l}$ and $\bar{Y_m},\bar{X_m}$ are given. Now I wonder how I cans tart to get an unbiased estimator?

My idea was to use the 'normal/one-sample' formula and just put weights (correcting for different sample size between the two independent sets of data) in front.

An estimator for $b_1$ would be: (X'X)$^{-1}$X'Y without matrices: $\frac{\sum X_iY_i - N \bar{Y}\bar{X}}{\sum X_i^2 -N \bar{X}^2}$

which I wanted to modify to $\frac{l}{m+l} \frac{\sum X_iY_i - L \bar{Y_l}\bar{X_l}}{\sum X_i^2 - L \bar{X_l}^2} + \frac{m}{m+l} \frac{\sum X_iY_i - M \bar{Y_m}\bar{X_m}}{\sum X_i^2 - M \bar{X_m}^2}$

The capital M and L denoting the respective sample size.

Now I am not sure if my result is right, as I cannot show if it is unbiased, to be honest.

Is it unbiased in probabilistic terms? Or is it just a wrong estimator?

Comment: Running a single multiple regression on all observations with X and an indicator for the sample as the two regressors will give you an unbiased estimator of the true linear effect of X (given the linear structure of the model is correct).

Comment: Thanks. I can assume the linear structure as shown above as correct. However, I don't see the point of using a dummy. From the "consistency of the sample mean" I have to assume with greater sample size both sets get the same means (in X and Y respectively) and therefor the dummies' significance will reach zero, or?

Answer (score 3):

The unbiasedness poperty of the OLS estimator in the linear regression model is a finite-sample property, and it is based on a specific assumption of the model being correct -that the regressors are "strictly exogenous to the error term", namely $E(u_i|\mathbf X)=0$.

So if you accept that this assumption holds, as you indicate in a comment, and so the OLS estimator for each sample has the unbiasedness property, then **a combination of the two will be unbiased if it is a linear combination with weights adding up to unity (but not necessarily a convex combination)**. Namely, let $\hat B_{1l}$ and $\hat B_{1m}$ be the two single sample estimators. Consider an estimator that it is some function of the two:

$$\hat B^* = h\left(\hat B_{1l},\hat B_{1m}\right) $$
Its expected value is

$$E\left[\hat B^*\right] = E\left[h\left(\hat B_{1l},\hat B_{1m}\right)\right] $$

If $h()$ is *not* an affine function, then by Jensen's inequality 
$$E\left[h\left(B_{1l},\hat B_{1m}\right)\right] \neq h\left(E\hat B_{1l},E\hat B_{1m}\right)$$
and in general $\hat B^*$ won't be unbiased.

Assume now that $h()$ is affine namely

$$\hat B^* = a_0 +a_1\hat B_{1l}+a_2\hat B_{1m} $$

with $a$'s being constants. Then

$$E\left[\hat B^*\right] = a_0 +a_1E\hat B_{1l}+a_2E\hat B_{1m} =a_0 + (a_1+a_2)B_{1}$$

For
$$E\left[\hat B^*\right] = B_{1} \Rightarrow a_0 = (1-a_1-a_2)B_{1} $$

This condition depends on the unknown coefficient $B_1$ *except* if we set $a_0=0,\; a_1=1-a_2$, in which case it will hold always. In principle, these conditions do not exclude the possibility that $a_2 >1, a_1<0$, in which case we have no longer a convex combination. But interpreting negative weights is difficult (although in forecasting literature negative weights have been found to increase efficiency occasionally), so usually we take the convex combination, i.e. $0<a_1<1,\; 0<a_2<1, \; a_1+a_2=1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But isn't that very similar to my solution, stated in the first part, where my estimator hat weights from the "SHARE" of observations? And would $\hat{B}= \frac{\bar{Y}_l -\bar{Y}_m}{\bar{X}_l - \bar{X}_m}$ be an as good unbiased estimator?

Comment: a) My answer showed theoretically that you get unbiasedness only if you apply a linear combination (and not just a convex combination as was stated in your question) b) Have you tried to consider the expected value $E\hat{B}$ of the estimator you propose in your comment?

Comment: okay, I need a linear, not a convex combination. Sorry, I must have confused something.  Okay, thanks. The expected value I obtain is probably wrong, this is why I cannot solve the task. I get:   $E(\bar{X_l})= E(\bar{X_m}) = \mu_X$ which makes the denominator 0.  And this makes both fractions going to infinity, but as they are connected with a minus, it goes to zero in the end. Can this be true?

Comment: No it is not because $E(\hat{B})=E\left(  \frac{\bar{Y}_l -\bar{Y}_m}{\bar{X}_l - \bar{X}_m}\right) \neq  \frac{E\bar{Y}_l -E\bar{Y}_m}{E\bar{X}_l - E\bar{X}_m}$

Comment: Oh - really not? Any hints how I can obtain the true expected value?

Comment: You should look up Jensen's Inequality to see why the equality does not hold, and why usually there are no "hints" for the expected value of non-linear functions of random variables.

Comment: Well I know Jensen's Inequality. It basically says, that a line between two points in a convex set is within the set. Maybe you can clarify, what specifically would help me to apply it here? Regarding the case of the expected value: I thought the expected value follows rules such as E(A)+E(B)= E(A+B), E(A)-E(B)= E(A-B),E(A)*E(B)= E(A*B) and so on. Was this false information?

Comment: Partly false. You need to look up the properties of expected value, and how they are affected by linearity/non-linearity, independence and non-independence.

Comment: Is this standard procedure / documented anywhere? It seems to me like it opens up a can of worms in terms of being required to assign latent classes to any sample used in OLS. How do you distinguish different samples when the sampling methodology is less cut and dry?

Comment: @ssdecontrol I am not sure I am following you. What I wrote is not any kind of procedure. It is a textbook-level result that is based a) on the _assumed_ unbiasedness of OLS estimator, and b) the linearity of the expected value operator. There is no need to distinguish between the samples in any way -they could partly overlap for example.

Comment: My point is that you could arbitrarily split up a sample and show that, in general, OLS is in fact biased because of Jensen's inequality. I guess what I meant by "procedure" was properly dividing up the sample and determining the form of $h$. I guess knowing the sample design would help?

Comment: @ssdecontrol My answer showed only that a linear combination of OLS estimators with weights that add up to unity _preserves_ unbiasedness, _if_ it already exists, i.e. if the individual estimators are unbiased. It does not _induce_ unbiasedness if the individual estimators are already biased (on the contrary, in such a case it preserves the existence of bias). Can you elaborate on how one would use Jensen's Inequality here?

Comment: I used Jensen's the same way you did. Your answer implies that proving an estimator is unbiased, in practice, requires showing that $\hat{\beta}=\sum{m}a_i \beta _k$ for $m$ arbitrary subsamples that in union cover the entire sample. You could define a "sample" as indexed by ${1,\dots ,n}$ where $n$ is the number of observations, and a subsample is indexed by a subset of that. I don't believe your math is wrong, I'm just wondering whether this condition holds trivially in some way I'm not seeing, or whether there's a stricter notion of a "sample" in use here.